# WKWebView can not load the local HTML with the local front

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

When I change to use WKWebView to load the local HTML, there are some issues. Due to the auto scaling, I have added the code to the html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

For now, the html can be loaded, but the front type is not correct. Obviously, the right one(WKWebView) is not the same with the left one(UIWebView). I use the local front type in the project.

[image]
[image]

I wonder if I need to add something else to load the html with the correct front type. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario:

WkWebView loading is through string html.
WkWebView is using local .css.
Fonts are local and are added at top level project.
Entries for fonts are provided in appName-info.plist under key Fonts provided by application.

Solution:

Add font face in .css at top level as follows

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'FontFamily';
    src: local('FontFamily'),url('FontFileName.otf') format('opentype');
}
```